# Check if an array of string contains a regex string

Tags: regex, groovy

I need to find if a particular string is included in the string array. I have written the below code and it does the job but is there any groovier way to do this?

```
boolean isApplePresent = false
randomItemList = ['red apple', 'dog', 'cat']
for(i = 0; i < randomItemList.size(); i++) {
    if(randomItemList[i] ==~ ".*apple.*") {
        isApplePresent = true
        break
    }
}

println(isApplePresent) //returns true
```

Comment: Try using the `any()` method: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_any_every.htm

Answer (score 0):

As per @barmar's comment I tried using `any` and this too works.

```
isApplePresent = randomItemList.any{e-> e ==~ ".*apple.*"}
```